# Вывод данных с помощью фильтров

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

Здравствуйте, сейчас сижу мучаюсь над проблемой вывода модального окна с содержимым, с помощью jquery. В общем хочу сделать следующее:

1. Сначала я выбираю промежуток времени;
2. Затем выбираю из списка Фильтрация и при выборе какого-то option, должно открываться МОДАЛЬНОЕ ОКНО, в котором я буду задать определенные параметры для дальнейшего построение запроса и соответственно выводить в таблицу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Речь о подмножестве option?

Comment: <select id="effectTypes" onchange="statusSelect();">
                <option value="hz">Выберите</option>
                <option id="napr">По направлениям</option>
                <option id="god">По году поступления</option>
</select>

Comment: Допустим я выбрал По направлениям, и открывается модальное окно со множеством чекбоксов и выбираю какие мне нужны направления, и нажимаю на кнопку показать, окно закрывается и строиться таблица с запрашиваемыми данными.

Answer (score 0):

Для решение проблемы, использовал bootstrap с модальными окнами и соответственно создал несколько модальных окон для каждого option и при выборе определенного option выдает нужное модальное окно с содержимым, в качестве таблицы используется jqgrid библиотека